# How to deploy a GCP HTTPS load balancer via terraform + lb-http module that only has a bucket backend?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

This is something that is very much possible and have done many times before using the UI in GCP.

The main problem I'm having when using terraform and the [lb-http](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/GoogleCloudPlatform/lb-http/google/latest) module.

I currently have a deployment with terraform working, but it was only possible by assigning a backend service with no backends as the 'default' and then routing all paths to my bucket where I have a webapp.

If I try to provide the reference to the bucket itself -- it will not work and if I try to omit the 'backends' property altogether in the terraform definitions, it will say it is mandatory.

Current code:

```
module "gce-lb-http" {
  source  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/lb-http/google"
  version = "~> 4.4"
  project = "redacted"
  name    = "main"
  address = google_compute_global_address.main.address


  http_forward                    = true
  https_redirect                  = true
  managed_ssl_certificate_domains = ["redacted"]
  create_address                  = false
  url_map                         = google_compute_url_map.main.self_link
  create_url_map                  = false
  ssl                             = true

  backends = {
    default = {
      description                     = null
      protocol                        = "HTTP"
      port                            = 80
      port_name                       = "http"
      timeout_sec                     = 10
      connection_draining_timeout_sec = null
      enable_cdn                      = false
      security_policy                 = null
      session_affinity                = null
      affinity_cookie_ttl_sec         = null
      custom_request_headers          = null
      custom_response_headers         = null

      health_check = {
        check_interval_sec  = null
        timeout_sec         = null
        healthy_threshold   = null
        unhealthy_threshold = null
        request_path        = "/"
        port                = 80
        host                = null
        logging             = null
      }

      log_config = {
        enable      = true
        sample_rate = 1.0
      }
      groups = []

      iap_config = {
        enable               = false
        oauth2_client_id     = ""
        oauth2_client_secret = ""
      }
    }
  }

}


resource "google_compute_url_map" "main" {
  // note that this is the name of the load balancer
  name            = "main"
  default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.redacted-backend-bucket.self_link

  host_rule {
    hosts        = ["*"]
    path_matcher = "allpaths"
  }

  path_matcher {
    name            = "allpaths"
    default_service = google_compute_backend_bucket.redacted-backend-bucket.self_link
  }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? If not, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This configuration (i.e. load balancing to a Cloud Storage bucket only) isn't currently possible with the lb-http module. Currently, the `backends` parameter is mandatory, so it must always be specified.

The code samples in the `/examples` directory in the repository show how to route a subset of URLs to a bucket, but not all of them (e.g. the [https-gke](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-lb-http/tree/master/examples/https-gke) example). There is also currently an [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-lb-http/issues/198) on this topic.

The [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setup-global-ext-https-buckets) suggests that you must manually create the resources to achieve setting up load balancing to a Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: ehrm, I've had no problem doing this, I'll post an answer with the correct config.